# Is there a standard way to capture keyboard inputs that works in a c++ application for linux and windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, input

For a c++ game so it can run on a linux machine or windows machine?

Like with windows I would use hooks but I wondered how I can do the same thing so my game can run on linux machines too?

Comment: C++ doesn't assume the existence of a keyboard..?

Comment: C++ implementations expose `stdin` - which can reasonably be assumed to be the keyboard for the purpose of simple textual games - through the `std::cin` stream.  You need to use OS specific functions if you want unbuffered I/O or raw hardware-level keyboard scan codes.  If you use some game library, or XWindows for that matter, it may well provide unbuffered I/O and keyboard event callbacks/hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a library to abstract the differences between platforms.

If you are writing a simple console-based application, then the C++ standard library is enough.  For a graphical application, you will want to use something like LibSDL.  It is common for games to use SDL.  This allows the same game to run on Windows, Linux, and OS X without too much modification between platforms.

GLFW and SFML are some other alternatives.

If are writing a complex console-based application, like NetHack, you will need a library for console abstraction such as ncurses.